# Knockout checked - bind to string literal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a data stored in Name/Value pairs with an associated data type (text, checkbox, password, etc.,)

I am trying to use knockout to bind the checked attribute like so

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.Value">
```

My problem is that the values come in as string literals, so instead of getting the value of (true) I get it like this ("true")..which regardless of "true"/"false" it will automatically mark it as true.

I would like to be able to run a simple function that test if it is "true"/"false" and if so return the boolean value back, so knockout will bind properly.

any suggestions?

UPDATE: Data is essentially in the following format

```
    {
      "ID": 276,
      "Name": "DefaultIsCallToOrder",
      "Value": "false",
      "Sequence": 7,
      "DataType": "checkbox",
    },
    {
      "ID": 277,
      "Name": "DefaultIsFeatured",
      "Value": "false",
      "Sequence": 8,
      "DataType": "checkbox",
    },
```

Comment: Can you give any links about how this approach works (I mean expression data-bind="checked: $root.Value")? i'll be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a computed value to your view model, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ubL6/1/):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked()" /> My check box <br/>
```

---

```
function AppViewModel(someValue) {
    this.checkBoxValue = someValue;
    this.isChecked = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.checkBoxValue == "true";   
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel("true"));
```

As an alternative you can of course compare directly with the string value in your view, that would defeat the purpose of separation of view from view model though:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBoxValue=='true'" /> My checkbox is here
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: isChecked is not defined; Bindings value: checked: isChecked()"

Comment: @afreeland: did you add the `isChecked` function to your view model? Check the jsFiddle for a working example

Comment: my viewmodel originally looks like this..
var json = $('#data').html();
    var o = $.parseJSON(json);
    var viewModel = o;
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

Comment: @afreeland: you will have to extend `o` with `isChecked` etc., of course this can't work if you don't change your viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

There's now a simpler way than creating a property on your view model, using the `checkedValue` binding (added in version 3.0):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.Value, checkedValue: 'true'" />
```

From  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html  :

> Additional parameters
>
> - checkedValue
>
> If your binding also includes checkedValue, this defines the value
> used by the checked binding instead of the element’s value attribute.
> This is useful if you want the value to be something other than a
> string (such as an integer or object), or you want the value set
> dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can just create a JavaScript-function that you call to do the comparison:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isTrue(val) {
   return (val === "true");
}
</script>
```

And then you modify your input to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isTrue($root.Value)">
```

Comment: This worked for the initial page load..it will properly check or uncheck the box depending on the value.  However, it doesnt appear to bind...if I check or uncheck a box the value remains the same as the initial page load value.